# Access VuePress docs from within a VueJS app?

Tags: vuejs2, vuepress

Suppose I have a VueJS app that requires the user to login/authenticate in order to use my app. If I then build documentation with VuePress and house that documentation within the app, is there a way I can link to the documentation from within the app?

For example:

- User logs into my app
- User clicks a "documentation" button inside my
  app
- User is presented the documentation that I built with VuePress
- Users who do not login to my app do not have access to the
  documentation housed inside the app

Is this possible? Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best solution, but right now I am building the vuepress files into the same `/dist` folder as the main app.

Comment: @ydennis How do you access them when they're deployed? Do you just have additional router links to the docs?

Comment: Well anything in `/dist` is served statically same as your index.html, so when someone navigates to the folder calles /docs it will serve the index.html from that folder.